# Pulling/Cloning already deployed application from shinyapps.io

Tags: r, git, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server

I have deployed an application from my home computer on the shinyapps.io server.

How, can I pull the same app instance to another computer.
I have already added the token and have permissions to my account from the second computer.
Is there cloneApp() or pullApp() function or something like this? or I would have to host it on github and then I have more freedom.

Thanks

Comment: Could you just `scp` the relevant files from the shinyapps.io server to wherever you need it?

Comment: yeah thats an option, better would be to host it on github for example as it provides more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to host the code on github and then the only thing you have on shinyapps.io would be a pointer to pull down the relevant code from your github repo.

```
server.R:
eval(parse(text=RCurl::getURL("https://gist.github.com/myrepo", ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)))

ui.R:
eval(parse(text=RCurl::getURL("https://gist.github.com/myrepo", ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)))
```

That way, the app will serve at shinyapps.io, and you can clone that github repo from wherever you like.

Take a look at [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/ACgJu_c_Yks) as well.

Comment: But this is not very dynamic, I have to create new gist all the time when I update the code. I hosted my code on bitbucket and then basically pull on different machines and push back.

Using your suggestion, I then wouldn't have to give pull rights to a new machine. This is good to know but I get an error, If I try this  


Error in parse(text = RCurl::getURL("https://gist.github.com/myRepo/asdaf7de68edfced937",  : 
  <text>:1:1: unexpected '<'
1: <